# Problem using eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm absolutely new to ubuntu.
I'm going to program java using eclipse, so I extracted file "eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz" in some folder, and tried to run "eclipse" in the extracted folder.  But it showed the following message:

```
"Could not display eclipse.    There is no application installed for
'executable' files. Do you want to search for an application to open
this file?"
```

I clicked "yes" and installed "pypar2" as its recommendation. But still I cannot execute this file.  What should I do to start using eclipse?  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you have a Java Development Kit installed?

Answer (score 1):

you have a variable called `$PATH` in your bash. any executable that in in one of the folders displayed by

```
$ echo $PATH
```

can be executed by giving the name of the executable in any working directory:

```
$ eclipse
```

but if your eclipse is not in one of the paths in `$PATH` you either need to go to the directory where eclipse is and use

```
$ ./eclipse
```

or use the full path: e.g.

```
$ /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

i usually create a launcher that i can drag to the bar on the left:

1) create a file with the contents (adapt the paths to your needs):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=eclipse 4.5 mars
Comment=
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

2. make the file executable (e.g. with nautlius)
3. drag and drop the file (again, using nautilus) to the launcher bar.

Comment: Hi, I have done same thing. But when I open eclise, it shows error: no such directory: /opt/eclipse/eclipse  I checked and directory is there.

Comment: `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` should be an executable file (not a directory). but nowadays i suggest you install eclipse via `snap`...

Comment: yes eclipse executable is there in /opt/eclipse folder.